To buffer or not to buffer - fputc() vs fwrite()
Edit: My bench marking code was wrong (SIZE / BUFSIZ in fwrite() should only be BUFSIZ), so everything is cleared up: in my case buffered fwrite() is giving better performance.
I try to speed optimize my C program that writes variable length codes to a file. Right now I have a buffer of size BUFSIZ which I fill with my bits until he is filled and then I write the buffer to my file using fwrite(). The resulting file can vary in size (from bytes to GiB, so from very few write calls to many calls) as I implemented the huffman algorithm for file compression.
I bench marked writing content to a file using fputc() and fwrite() (in BUFSIZ sized chunks). Surprisingly, fputc() outperforms fwrite() for 1 GiB, but the opposite is the case for 8 MiB. So why is fputc() sometimes faster than fwrite() and sometimes not, and secondly is it better to buffer or not to buffer when wanting best performance for IO operations?
The code I used for bench marking (as I am lazy this code is from chatGPT):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 8388608
// #define SIZE 1073741824

int main()
{
    FILE* file;
    char* buffer = malloc(SIZE);

    // Fill buffer with some data
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        buffer[i] = 'A';
    }

    // Benchmark fwrite
    file = fopen("fwrite_test", "wb");
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE / BUFSIZ; i++) {
        fwrite(buffer + i * BUFSIZ, sizeof(char), SIZE / BUFSIZ, file);
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    fclose(file);
    printf("fwrite: %f seconds\n", (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // Benchmark fputc
    file = fopen("fputc_test", "wb");
    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        fputc(buffer[i], file);
    }
    end = clock();
    fclose(file);
    printf("fputc : %f seconds\n", (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}

For 8 MiB I get this speed:
fwrite: 0.001915 seconds
fputc : 0.092756 seconds

-> fwrite is 48 times faster
And for 1 GiB:
fwrite: 14.579728 seconds
fputc : 3.512994 seconds

-> fputc is 4 times faster
And this is the code I actually want to optimize (I know that writeBits() and writeByte() shouldn't use writeBit() for good performance, I haven't implemented proper logic for them yet):
#include "bitHandler.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Struct with all needed Infos to write buffered bits to a file
typedef struct bitBuffer {
    unsigned char* buffer;
    unsigned int bufferPosition;
    int bitPosition;
    FILE* output;
} bitBuffer_t;

// UINT_FAST64_WIDTH is defined in c23, assuming 64 is reaasonable if compiler doesn't support c23
#ifndef UINT_FAST64_WIDTH
#define UINT_FAST64_WIDTH 64
#endif

// Write a single bit to buffer and then to file
extern void writeBit(int bit, bitBuffer_t* bitBuffer)
{
    if (bit) {
        bitBuffer->buffer[bitBuffer->bufferPosition] |= 1u << (7 - bitBuffer->bitPosition);
    } else {
        bitBuffer->buffer[bitBuffer->bufferPosition] &= ~(1u << (7 - bitBuffer->bitPosition));
    }
    // Go to next byte if current one is full, flush buffer if it is full
    if (bitBuffer->bitPosition == 7) {
        if (bitBuffer->bufferPosition == BUFSIZ - 1) {
            flush(bitBuffer);
        } else {
            ++bitBuffer->bufferPosition;
        }
        bitBuffer->bitPosition = 0;
    } else {
        ++bitBuffer->bitPosition;
    }
}

// write multiple bits
extern void writeBits(uint_fast64_t bits, int nbits, bitBuffer_t* bitBuffer)
{
    int i;
    int bit;
    for (i = 0; i < nbits; i++) {
        bit = (bits >> (UINT_FAST64_WIDTH - 1 - i)) & 1u;
        writeBit(bit, bitBuffer);
    }
}

// write byte
extern void writeByte(unsigned char byte, bitBuffer_t* bitBuffer)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        writeBit((byte >> (7 - i)) & 1u, bitBuffer);
    }
}

// flush the remaining bits in buffer to file
extern void flush(bitBuffer_t* bitBuffer)
{
    fwrite(bitBuffer->buffer, sizeof(char),
        (bitBuffer->bitPosition == 0) ? bitBuffer->bufferPosition : bitBuffer->bufferPosition + 1,
        bitBuffer->output);
    bitBuffer->bufferPosition = 0;
    bitBuffer->bitPosition = 0;
}



C I/O buffers for you already, so you are buffering buffered data.

The third parameter of fwrite(buffer + i * BUFSIZ, sizeof(char), SIZE / BUFSIZ, file); looks wrong to me.

@Dúthomhas I didn't know that. Seems like it is worth buffering read operations but not write operations. Do you have an idea why fwrite is so much faster for small amount of data?

@pmacfarlane Yes you're right, it should be BUFSIZ, and then fwrite outperforms fputc constantly. So the bench mark code was wrong adn thus all my questions redundant

@Dúthomhas Buffering buffered data gives me better performance. As pmacfarlane pointed out my code was wrong and it is worth it to use fwrite(). I don't know why as I'd expect C intern buffering to be sufficient

Be aware that clock measure the CPU time and not the end-user wall-clock time. It might not be a problem here with a sequential code but better be safe than sorry. PS: it turns out ChatGPT generate this bad profiling code unsurprisingly (without safe checks either). By the way, note you should flush caches before the benchmark and wait between so the firmware can move data internally between the different kind of SSD cells (eg. SLC cache) assuming you use a SSD (the same thing happen with HDDs with caches).

@JérômeRichard The bug was ironically introduced by me. I am aware that ChatGPT writes unsafe code. I only used it because safe checks aren't important here as I'm only experimenting and don't use the code afterwards

@TheGlibber, With SIZE so large, better code would check the allocation success.

"Seems like it is worth buffering read operations but not write operations"  That is very counter-intuitive.  Consider a metaphor in which you work at a publishing house where the editor sits on the ninth floor while your desk is in the basement.  Your job is to bring books to the editor, and the writer is giving you one page at a time (fast author, 10 pages per second).  Unbuffered writes has you going up the stairs for every sheet of paper.  With a buffered write, you wait until you've collected enough sheets to fill a book and then you go up the stairs once.

Ok. Another way to say the same thing regarding the benchmark is that the order matters. The second time you write in the same file can be less expensive for many (OS-related) reasons (including FS-related low-level caching and page one). A simple naive test can be at least to put that in a loop and to check also what happen in a reverse order. Very few SSD can provide a sustained write (due to the aforementioned SLC cache).

Not seeing a sync call anywhere in your code so I don't know what time you are measuring.
